# From Hex to Binary and removing Binary digits

Tags: python

I have this:

```
   A    
0  FF5   
1  A02   
2  5B1
```

I want to convert the values from `A` to binary and drop down the last 2 positions of the binary code.

```
FF5 = 0000111111110101  --> 00001111111101
A02 = 101000000010      --> 1010000000
5B1 = 10110110001       --> 101101100

       A     
    0  00001111111101   
    1  1010000000  
    2  101101100
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? a hint for a basic method: the [`bin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bin) built-in will take any integer and return the binary as string; the [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) constructor can convert a string to an int with an argument `base=16` for hex inputs

Comment: Why does FF5 have extra leading bits in its binary representation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get binary representation without leading  `0b`

```
n = format(int("FF5", base=16),'b') # returns str '111111110101'
```

Drop `2` positions from the binary code using slicing:

```
n[:-2] # '1111111101'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly do that, try this,

```
hexstr = "A02" #--> your hex string

dec = int(hexstr, 16)
binary = bin(dec).lstrip("0b") #--> strip leading 0b from string

print(binary[:-2])
```

**Output:**

```
1010000000
```